# Twitterizer API Questions

Tags: c#, wpf, api, twitter, twitterizer

I've recently been playing around with the awesome Twitterizer Twitter API using C# WPF in Visual Studio 2008. It's been working the most part, but I do have some questions about it.

1) How can I make it so that the login screen is a different windows that closes when you log in, unless there is a login failure?

2) How can I make it so that it tells the user that their login information is incorrect?

3) How can I make it save the user's login information so that they don't have to enter again?

4) How can I make a character countdown when a user is posting a status and not let it be posted if it is over 140 characters?

Sorry if these questions seem kind of noobish. i'm not very good at C#, especially since this is my first time using the WPF framework.

Comment: These are all very general problems. Perhaps once you start hacking away at a solution you could get a better perspective on the problem and ask more focused questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is several questions.  You should ask them separately.

**How to make Login a different window**

Add a new Window to your project.  Implement your login screen there.  Show the new window when the app starts up (or whenever it is appropriate to do so).

**How to display login error messages**

When the "Log in" button is clicked in the window, execute the login.  If it fails (you get an exception), display a dialog box, otherwise close the login window.

**How to save the user's login information**

You should save such information to the protected store instead of writing it to a file.  Save it after a successful login.  Load it when the application starts.

**How to make a character countdown**

Add a new "CharactersLeft" dependency property to your user control or window.  Add a PropertyChangedCallback to your Text property (I assume you have one - it should be a DependencyProperty as well and your TextBox should be bound to it).  In the PropetyChangedCallback, update the CharactersLeft value.  Bind a TextBlock to the CharactersLeft value.

**How to prevent posting if CharactersLeft is negative**

If you are using an ICommand, implement CanExecute.  If you are using a RoutedCommand, implement OnCanExecute.  If you are directly handling the button click, consider using commands instead, or set a trigger on your button button so that it becomes disabled whenever CharactersLeft is less than zero.  (You will need a IValueConverter for this, or you can just have a separate property.)